# IOS How to add a view next to another view?

Tags: uiview, ios4, uilabel

I have a situation like this
I want to add a UILabel next to an  UILabel dynamically.
But the position of the 2nd label depends on the length of the string of the 1st label which is not fixed.
How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you set the new text to the first label, access `frame` property of your label.
The position for the second label would be :

```
CGRect f = firstLabel.frame;
CGRect f2 = CGRectMake(f.origin.x + f.size.width,
                       f.origin.y,
                       theWidthYouWant,
                       f.size.height);
secondLabel.frame = f2;
```

The second label is now next to the first.

If you want to add a new label to the container view, use `initWithFrame:` initializer with the computed frame above.

Comment: f.size.width wont work as the position of the 2nd label depends on the length  of the string present in the 1st label not on the width of its label